# MySQL update column after several minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, events, triggers

i have a table USER with column :

```
+----------------------------------------+
|     Name      Active       Insert_Time |
+----------------------------------------+
|     mon         1          1481203712  |
|     tue         0          1481202788  |
|     wed         2          1481202581  |
|     thu         0          1479902588  |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I want use of event trigger in MySQL, if after five minute of insert data to database, just updated `Active` column in table USER. How is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, using [`EVENT In MySQL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) like

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
    DO
      UPDATE `USER`  SET Active = 1;
```